# With Lyx Math is there a way to "demote" a numerator line to make it a single line?

Tags: math-mode, lyx

Lyx and Latex complete newb.

Say I've started writing an equation... and I've got (x+2) on the top line and (y-2) on the bottom (denominator) and then I realise I want to dispense with the bottom line and just have (x+2) on the line ... is there some way to do that just using Lyx?

I realise you could do it quite easily by editing the Latex code.

Answer (score 2):

The following LyX LFUN does what you want:

```
command-sequence inset-select-all; cut; char-delete-backward; paste
```

Note that it has the secondary effect of modifying the clipboard.

If you want to use the LFUN as a keyboard shortcut, then go to Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts, press "New", paste the LFUN into the "Function" text box, click on the blank raised box, press the keyboard shortcut you want and then press "OK".

If you just want to experiment with the command without a keyboard shortcut (this is useful for developing the command in the first place and for tweaking it), you can go to View > Toolbars > Command buffer (on Linux the shortcut is alt + X if you prefer). Then enter the command in the toolbar at the bottom of the window that pops up, and press Enter.